# Thread.sleep slow down when application is in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background

I'm trying to create a screen recorder, using the new Lolipop Api.
So, i need a fast thread, capable of looping at least, at 10 fps.

However, after a few tests, i noticed a problem :
When my application is visible, the thread performs well.
But when i switch to another application or to the android home screen, the thread really slows down. 
And even without performing anything inside my thread

I suppose the problem come from the thread.sleep method. 
I launch this thread from an activity, and i've already tried to launch it from a service, with same results.
Anyway, i read that a service is not really the place to do that, cause it can be killed by the system anytime.

Any idea how to keep my thread reactive?
Or perhaps using a thread is not the good solution?

Here is the thread is use for testing :

```
 /** Thread used to capture images from screen */
  public class ImagesCaptureThread implements Runnable {

    /** fps wanted */
    private final static int _fps = 10;

    /** Delay between images */
    private final static int _delayBetweenImagesInMs = 1000 / _fps;

    /** Date used to calculate fps */
    private Date _fpsDate = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.i("My App", "start capturing images");
      _fpsDate = new Date();
      while (true) {
        try {
          long startProcessingTime = new Date().getTime();

          long elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - _fpsDate.getTime();
          Log.i("My App", "Fps : " + ((1000 * 1.0) / elapsedTime));
          _fpsDate = new Date(); // Re init date

          if (!_captureStarted) { // Stop capturing
            Log.i("My App", "stop capturing images");
            break;
          }

          // TO DO : Capture image

          // Calculate how many time we need to sleep before next image capture
          long processingTime = new Date().getTime() - startProcessingTime;
          long sleepTime = _delayBetweenImagesInMs - processingTime;
          if (sleepTime > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the logs i get :

```
02-17 00:39:39.291: I/My App(28012): start capturing images
02-17 00:39:39.392: I/My App(28012): Fps : 9.900990099009901
02-17 00:39:39.492: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:39.592: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:39.693: I/My App(28012): Fps : 9.900990099009901
02-17 00:39:39.793: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:39.893: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:39.994: I/My App(28012): Fps : 9.900990099009901
02-17 00:39:40.094: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:40.194: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
 [ THIS IS WHEN I SWITCH TO ANDROID HOME SCREEN ]
02-17 00:39:42.040: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.194244604316546
02-17 00:39:42.176: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.407407407407407
02-17 00:39:42.312: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.462686567164179
02-17 00:39:42.450: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.246376811594203
02-17 00:39:42.590: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.142857142857143
02-17 00:39:42.731: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.142857142857143
02-17 00:39:42.867: I/My App(28012): Fps : 7.407407407407407
 [ THEN I SWITCH BACK TO MY APPLICATION ]
02-17 00:39:44.731: I/My App(28012): Fps : 9.900990099009901
02-17 00:39:44.831: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:44.931: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:45.032: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:45.131: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.1010101010101
02-17 00:39:45.231: I/My App(28012): Fps : 10.0
02-17 00:39:46.234: I/My App(28012): stop capturing images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am pretty sure that the `Service` is better option then using Threads. As per Android documentation:

> Because a process running a service is ranked higher than a process
>   with background activities, an activity that initiates a long-running
>   operation might do well to start a service for that operation, rather
>   than simply create a worker thread—particularly if the operation will
>   likely outlast the activity. For example, an activity that's uploading
>   a picture to a web site should start a service to perform the upload
>   so that the upload can continue in the background even if the user
>   leaves the activity. Using a service guarantees that the operation
>   will have at least "service process" priority, regardless of what
>   happens to the activity.

More info about Processes (Services, Activities) and Threads (and their priorities) [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Services can be background and foreground, read a bit more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) (that may help you figure out if you implemented something wrong, so you can fix it).

As for your specific issue, try checking the `sleepTime` value, there may be some issue with that (unfortunately, I cannot test your example, but I would start by checking that value), and if you still cannot find out where the problem lies, then you should try using [Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) or [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html) to check your apps performance, and figure out why is fps lower when app is not visible...

Comment: Well, you were right.
I missed the part about [foreground services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

Now my thread seems to keep the prority.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Android developer, but it seems to me that the OS is just not scheduling your thread for execution as quickly as you would like... The sequence of events looks something like this:

- Your thread is running
- Your thread calls `Thread.sleep(X)`
- The OS suspends your thread
- X ms pass and your thread is now "executable/runnable" again
- The OS has another Y thread it needs to schedule for execution on a CPU. It take Z ms before your thread is selected and given CPU cycles.

It seems like Android gives much lower priority to threads from background apps which leads to what seems like a Z=36ms delay before your thread gets to execute.

One way to address this issue is to sleep less and skip iterations if you need to. You can sleep `sleepTime/10` ms for example, and on each iteration have a check to see if you should do a frame capture or not.

Comment: I finaly found the problem (i'm now using a foreground service).

But sleeping step by step was an interesting approach.

Thanks for your answer